# Tensorflow: Loss function which takes one-hot as argument

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

My LSTM RNN has to predict a single letter(Y), given preceding words before(X).
For example, if "Oh, say! can you see by the dawn's early ligh" is given as X, then Y would be "t"(part of National Anthem). Each Alpabets are one-hot coded. So, g in one-hot coded is for example, [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...,0,0,0,0,0,0].

`dataX:[batch_size,20,num_of_classes], dataY:[batch_size,1,num_of_classes]`

In this case, what loss function would be best for prediction?
Both X and Y are one-hot encoded, X are many and Y is one.
I rarely find loss functions which takes one-hot as parameter(such as, parameter for logits or target).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the cross entropy between

**Y_** (ground truth) and **Y** (probabilities)

You could use a basic hand coded cross entropy like

```
y = tf.nn.softmax( logit_layer )
loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_mean( y_ * tf.log(y) ))
```

Or you could use the built in TensorFlow function

```
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits( labels=y_, logits=logit_layer)
```

Your **Y** output would be something like [0.01,0.02,0.01,.98,0.02,...] and your **logit_layer** is just the raw output before applying softmax.

Comment: Thank you for answering:) In my case, I passed output from lstm cell to `tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected`, and passed the output from FC Layer to loss function, by  `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=Y_one_hot, logits=outputs_from_FC)`. I guess this also works.

Comment: By the way, is multiplication in loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_mean( y_ * tf.log(y) )) the right way to calculate loss? Usually for loss, people do subtraction rather than multiplication.

Comment: The loss function I hand wrote is inferior.  Use the tensorflow function. To answer your question it is log loss, and multiplication is correct in this case.

Comment: So, let me be more specific.  Here is the wiki page for *cross entropy* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy.  It is different than square error by nature.  For example, let's say we have **Y_** a&b of [1,0,0] and our response is **Y**a [.98,.01,.01] and **Y**b [.98,.005,.015].  The square error will be different for **a** and **b** where as the cross entropy won't be as much (certainly not how I wrote it).  Using sum of squares has the byproduct of training the system to make the zero **Y_**s equal, but that's not really important.

Comment: If this answers your question please consider marking it as the answer.